# Comma Delinated string, of Ids, from Array of Objects. RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why doesn't this work?

I have an array of Objects, one of the attributes is the db id. I can make the array like so.

`qc_parts.map!{|a| a.id}`

However when I want to just make it a string. With

`qc_parts.map!{|a| a.id}.join(",")`

I only get an array out. I've also tried `.to_s` & `.to_a`
Any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qc_parts.map!{|a| a.id}.join(",")` will *return* a string, but it will not to put that value into the variable `qc_parts`. To do that you have to do

```
qc_parts = qc_parts.map{|a| a.id}.join(",")
```

If I've misunderstood, and you actually are seeing the `join` method return an array, then something strange is going on.